# How redirect the button new of frontend to open a seblod form in Joomla 3?

Tags: articles, front-end, seblod

when I enter in frontend as super-user appear a button to create new articles, but this button open the Joomla predeterminate editor and I want that open the seblod from that I designed to create articles.

How redirect the button new of frontend to open a seblod form?

Thaks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
1. htaccess redirect
2. default configuration for default article type
3. set a direct link via menu to form creation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

$link = JRoute::_('write url');
$app->redirect($link,$msg);